# SPI using one wire

Tags: spi

I need to communicate between a transmitter and a receiver using visible light therefore i have only one communication channel. so i was wondering if SPI interface can be implemented using one-wire only? if not, what is the alternative that can reach high rates?

Comment: That is what I am intending to do. The project was formerly implemented using UART but I want to increase the communication rate therefore I want to convert to SPI

Comment: FDTI UART chips exist with arbitrary bitrates upto 10MBit so do cheap microcontroller. 2Mbit UART is a none-issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment you implement the data transmission over one wire it ceases to be a SPI. 
You could use another serial protocol like [**one wire**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Wire) or **UART** (if you send commands only one way).

The difference between SPI and UART is, you need a to have clock for SPI, where for UART you don't send clock as a separate signal, but then you need to implement a clock recovery on the receiver end.

I recommend you use something that has UART communication, if your devices/ICs already have a SPI, use SPI to UART converter IC.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the problem is that I need to communicate using high rates that are not supported by UART protocol

Comment: well you need to implement the clock recovery then. 

How high are the "high reates" you're refering to?

Comment: "The project was formerly implemented using UART but I want to increase the communication rate therefore I want to convert to SPI" 
Again SPI over only one "wire" is a no go. You need to do your own serial protocol. You need to do a clock recovery and come up with some start or stop bits so you know when you are receiving the message. This is basically what UART does.

Comment: mmm. I mean by high rates 1-2 Mbps. is this achievable using UART?

Comment: most of the UART chips support 115200 as max, but some support 921600 and some even 1843200, so if you find one you solved your issue.
I think this([SC16IS760](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/SC16IS740_750_760.pdf)) is what you need. It can run 1.152 Mbit/s, the input is I2c or SPI. 
Otherwise clock recovery is not that hard to do for 1M.  And start and stop bits can be pretty simple.


Also some comments say you should use I2C. This is a bad idea, because you need at 2 signals for i2c.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to communicate between a transmitter and a receiver using
>   visible light therefore i have only one communication channel.

It's not too complicated to get this to work at even hundreds of MHz. One method (it works for me) is to feed your data into a scrambler because this ensures the actual transmissted data is always toggling. You need it toggle because if your payload data is asynchronous it can't be guaranteed to be toggling. This basically sets the spectrum of the signal to have zero dc content and this helps the receiver to lock-on and produce a clock.

There are also various parallel to serial chips that can do this at very fast rates and they have a matching chip that does the serial to parallel conversion process. This is also an option I've used several times. Look for SERDES chips at TI and MAXIM - I think the Maxim part number is something like MAX9205 - it's has a ten bit parallel port and is either the transmit device or the receive device. You *could* transmit clock and data a la SPI on two of the pins and still have 8 left over for "other" stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [IRDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_Data_Association) rather than inventing a non-standard protocol. There are a number of speeds possible in IRDA: : SIR (115kbps), MIR (1Mbps), FIR (4Mbps), and VFIR (16Mbps)- with others up to 10G in various stages.